White screen on Mapbox map in Flutter web
I've added Mapbox to my Flutter project for Web, but I seem to just get a white screen, with the map not showing. This happens on both Chrome and Edge.
Because the Flutter SDK only works on mobile, I had to implement Mapbox GL JS. Because I use Flutter, the approach was once again a bit different.
To start, I have added these lines in my index.html:
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

Because I work in a Flutter environment, I've made a separate file called mapbox.dart to hold this code:
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;
import "package:universal_html/html.dart";


void registerMapboxFactory(String mapboxAccessToken) {
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('mapbox-html', (int viewId) {
    final mapDiv = DivElement()
      ..id = 'map'
      ..style.width = '100%'
      ..style.height = '100%';

    print('Map div created with id: ${mapDiv.id}');

    final scriptContent = '''
      console.log("Mapbox script loaded.");
      mapboxgl.accessToken = '$mapboxAccessToken';
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed.");
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: 'map',
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
          center: [-74.0066, 40.7135],
          zoom: 12
        });
        console.log("Mapbox map initialized.");
      });
    ''';

    final scriptElement = ScriptElement()
      ..type = 'text/javascript'
      ..innerHtml = scriptContent;
    document.head!.append(scriptElement);
    print('Mapbox script appended to document head.');

    return mapDiv;
  });
}

On the page where I show the map, I've placed this in the initState:
final String mapboxAccessToken = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).mapboxAccessToken;
registerMapboxFactory(mapboxAccessToken);

And then this on the place where the map should be shown:
Container(
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  child: const HtmlElementView(viewType: 'mapbox-html'),
),

Whenever I run the app, and open the page, I get the logging in the console:
Map div created with id: map
Mapbox script loaded.
Mapbox script appended to document head.
What I've checked and tried:

My access token is working.
The style ID is the standard one.
My account is active on Mapbox.
According to this, my browser emulators should support WebGL.
I don't see any network errors indicating CORS issue.
My access token has all standard public scopes.
My access token has no URL restrictions, and says "This token will work for requests originating from any URL."
If I add a colored background to the DivElement, I see that in the UI, so div is correctly added to the DOM..
I've pressed Invalidate Caches on Android Studio several times.
I removed old build files by hand.
I ran flutter clean and flutter build web --release.

